# Executing JDBC bulk operation

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a bulk JDBC operation executing concurrently (`PostgreSQL 9.4 jdbc driver`).  The operation is likely to run for 20-30 seconds. Now I need to understand what happens with the thread the operation is being executed in. I thought it just `slept` or `being await` until a DB-server start sending data back to JVM. So, I tried to check it in the debugger and now I'm not sure about that. Here's the example I wrote for test (I used spring for simplicity):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/applicationContext.xml");
        final Dao dao = (Dao) context.getBean("dao");
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Thread.currentThread().setName("Bulk Operation");
                dao.executeBulk(); //1, The bulk operation
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

I set the breakpoin at `//1` and after resuming I saw the following in the debugger:

[image]

So it seems the `Bulk thread` was neither `asleep` nor `awaiting`.

What the thread actually does while the sql-server prepares the data to be sent? How many resources does JVM spend to manage the thread?

Comment: Err, what exactly does the 'bulk operation *do*?

Comment: @EJP I my case it just a select operation from a large table.

Comment: Come off it. Show us.